# How to get callback when key expires in REDIS

Tags: python, redis, bottle

I'm developing application using Bottle. In my registration form, I'm confirming email by mail with a unique key. I'm storing this key in REDIS with expiry of 4 days. If user does not confirm email within 4 days, key gets expired. for this, I want to permanently delete the user entry from my database(mongoDB).

Ofcourse I dont require continous polling to my redis server to check whether key exists or not.

Is there any way to get a callback from Redis??

OR is there any other efficient way?

Comment: Please see [Notification of key expiration in redis python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964548/notification-of-key-expiration-in-redis-python) for an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This feature implemented in Redis 2.8, read about it here http://redis.io/topics/notifications

Answer (score 11):

There are no such callbacks in redis (not that I know of).

I would do it like this:

- when user signs up, [put his id into a sorted set](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) where the score is a timestamp (now + 4 days) and member is user id.
- have a periodic job that gets all records from that sorted set where timestamp is in the past.
- loop through those user ids and take actions (if he didn't confirm - delete all user's data).

Comment: More information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810020/how-to-handle-session-expire-basing-redis/11815594#11815594

Comment: Great technique, something I will copy if you do not mind ^_^