# Distributed cache with custom action on key expiration

Tags: caching, distributed

Is there any (preferably open source) distributed cache server that allows me to implement a custom action to run when a key's TTL expires? If not, is there any open source, light weight server I could potentially modify to make it do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a cache server, but rather a simple in memory key/value store - [redis](http://redis.io/) which can have expiration set on the keys - and since the version 2.8 supports notifications when keys expire ([How to get callback when key expires in REDIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174615/how-to-get-callback-when-key-expires-in-redis) and http://redis.io/topics/notifications)