# Flask-Caching call back event when key delete automatically

Tags: python, flask, flask-cache

I have one java app and flask app the java app will send some value to the flask app that I need to save it in the cache so I am using flask-caching and I am having some default time out in the flask caching.
The problem is once a key is deleted from the flask caching automatically based on the timeout I need to send the value to the java app which key is deleted. 
I am not sure how I how can know that a value is deleted automatically from cache do we have some call back a method in flask caching that will notify that value is deleted flask caching or suggest me what kind of caching I can use to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Redis Cache as the backend. You can use Redis notifications.

Basically the 2 steps would be.

1. SET the key using Flask Cache with Redis as a backend.
2. Subscribe via pub sub to Redis notifications from the Java App.

You could use a key prefix etc as well. So as to identify the notification of the key expiry in the Java app.

For implementation details, this answer [Notification of key expiration in redis python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23965234/5404694) will further help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help ref this link if someone is also looking for same things https://tech.webinterpret.com/redis-notifications-python/