# How to check if redis key is expired or not in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I had a issue with redis recently.
I set a key using redis.setex , then I want to print something after the key is expired.
I mean :

```
redis.setex('Hi',2,'Hello')
if redis.ttl <= 0:
    print('done')
```

but it won't work.
can't work with sleep or loops because the program has other parts to run ( it's a telegram bot ).
i would be thankful if someone help me with that.
sorry for bad English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification of key expiration in redis python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964548/notification-of-key-expiration-in-redis-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I didn't use those options but I found **threading Timer**!
used :

```
def something():
    .... #call another function to run
threading.Timer(redis.ttl(key),something).start()
```

and the problem solved.
idk if the program is optimized or not but 'When it is running properly, don't touch it' :)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: Check if the key exists**

If a key has expired the key is not in the database anymore.
This means, I know this is obvious, that if the key is here it has not expired ;)

So you can either run the command [EXISTS](https://redis.io/commands/exists) or retrieve the key.

**Option 2: Use Key Space Notifications**

what you can do is, you can have the database publishing an event when a key is expired/deleted. I invite you to look at this part of the documentation:
* [KeySpace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#:~:text=Timing%20of%20expired%20events)

So once the event occurs, Redis publishes an event on a channel, you can then use your Python and Subscribe to this

**Option 3: Use Redis Gears & Key Spaces Notifications**

The Redis community has a new module "[Redis Gears](http://redisgears.io/)" that could help you too. It is very similar to the options 2, the big differences are:

- the way you listen to the [key events](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/readers.html#keysreader) `gb.register(prefix='*', eventTypes=['expired'])`
- you can push the event to Redis Streams, publish an event or even process it in Python.

I hope I am helping you and you will find one of these options useful for your application