# Redis, session expiration, and reverse lookup

Tags: redis

I'm currently bulding a web app and would like to use Redis to store sessions. At login, the session is inserted into Redis with a corresponding user id, and expiration set at 15 minutes. I would now like to implement reverse look-up for sessions (get sessions with a certain user id). The problem here is, since I can't search the Redis keyspace, how to implement this. One way would be to have a redis set for each userId, containing all session ids. But since Redis doesn't allow expiration of an item in a set, and sessions are set to expire, there would be a ton of inexistent session ids in the sets.

What would be the best way to remove ids from sets on key expiration? Or, is there a better way of accomplishing what I want (reverse look-up)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On the current release branch of *Redis (2.6)*, you cannot have notifications when items are expired. It will probably change with the next versions.

In the meantime, to support your requirement, you need to manually implement expiration notification support. So you have:

```
session:<sessionid> -> a hash storing your session data - one of the field is <userid>
user:<userid> -> a set of <sessionid>
```

You need to remove `sessionid` from the user set when the session expires. So you can maintain a additional sorted set whose score is a timestamp.

When you create session 10 for user 100:

```
MULTI
HMSET session:10 userid:100 ... other session data ...
SADD user:100 10
ZADD to_be_expired <current timestamp + session timeout> 10
EXEC
```

Then, you need to build a daemon which will poll the zset to identify the session to expire ([`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore)). For each expired session, it has to maintain the data structure:

- pop the session out of the zset ([`ZREMRANGEBYRANK`](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank))
- retrieve session userid ([`HMGET`](https://redis.io/commands/hmget))
- delete session ([`DEL`](https://redis.io/commands/del))
- remove session from userid set ([`SREM`](https://redis.io/commands/srem))

The main difficulty is to ensure there is no race conditions when the daemon polls and processes the items. See my answer to this question to see how it can be implemented:

> [how to handle session expire basing redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810020/how-to-handle-session-expire-basing-redis/11815594#11815594)

Comment: As per **Redis 4.0.0**, [**HMSET is considered deprecated**](https://redis.io/commands/hmset). **Use HSET** in new code

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of Redis (2.8.0 and up) [Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) for `expired` events are supported. I.e. when a key with a TTL expires this event is triggered.

This is what to subscribe to:

```
'__keyevent@0__:expired'
```

So subscribing to this event allows you to have a single index for all sessions and you can remove the key from the index when the key expires.

Example:

Use a sorted set as a secondary index with the uid as the weight:

```
ZADD "idx-session-uid" <uid> <sessionkey>
```

Search for sessionkeys for a specific user with:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE "idx-session-uid" <uid> <uid>
```

When a session is deleted or expired we do:

```
ZREM "idx-session-uid" <sessionkey>
```