# TTL for a set member

Tags: redis, set, tagging, ttl

Is it possible in Redis to set TTL (time to live) not for a specific key, but for a member for a set?

I am using a structure for tags proposed by Redis documentation - the data are simple key-value pairs, and the tags are sets containing keys corresponding to each tag, e.g.

```
> SETEX id:id_1 100 'Lorem ipsum'
OK
> SADD tag:tag_1 id:id_1
(integer) 1
```

The key `id:id_1` will expire as expected but i don't see an efficient way to remove the corresponding member from the `tag:tag_1` set.

One way I came up is using a cron job containing a script which would remove expired keys from sets periodically - by adding all the tag names to another set and then iterating through all the tags, then all the ids corresponding to each tag and checking if corresponding key exists - if not, calling `SREM`.

I don't think it will be an efficient way and I would possibly like to keep the tags as clean as possible, because the size of the sets will probably affect performance of searching by multiple tags (`SINTER`). Is there a more "internal" way?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858291/3679900) could help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is not possible to directly expire items in list, sets, or zsets.

You need to implement a mechanism to be notified when the master item expires, so that you can maintain the corresponding sets accordingly.

See the answer to this question, I think it applies to your use case (replace session by id, and user by tag):

[Redis, session expiration, and reverse lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741476/redis-session-expiration-and-reverse-lookup/16747795#16747795)

Comment: Yes, it's a decent way and I'll probably handle the problem with something similar. Since the existence of expired members in tag sets isn't a problem in any other way then performance, I'll most likely use a periodically run cron istead of a deamon - to limit polls to a sufficient minimum.

Answer (score 82):

No, this isn’t possible (and [not planned either](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/135)). The [recommended](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/135#issuecomment-2361996) approach is to use an ordered set with score set to timestamp and then manually removing expired keys. To query for non-expired keys, you can use `ZRANGEBYSCORE $now +inf`, to delete expired keys, `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE -inf $now` will do the trick.

In my application, I simply issue both commands every time I query the set. I also combine this with (long) expiration time on the set itself to eventually purge unused sets.

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20161007055137/https://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-create-and-expire-list-items-in-redis/) walks through it in more detail.

Comment: this might be the best solution so far until Redis natively supports it. keep in mind tho, insert into sorted set will be O(logN).

Comment: The article link is broken, is there a new URL?

Comment: **@Bob Whitelock** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858291/3679900) could help

Answer (score 1):

You can not expire items in a list directly, but it's possible to register a lua script in your redis server and add this functionality to redis.
[Redis Expiration based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307425/redis-expiration-based-on-value)