# Redis store key without a value

Tags: redis, ttl

When using the Redis **expire** commands like **[`SETEX`](https://redis.io/commands/setex)** and **[`TTL`](https://redis.io/commands/ttl)**, there are scenarios in which there is no need for the key to hold a value at all, because the *time to live* acts as such.

*However, Redis requires any key to have a value.*

What would be the most reasonable value to use - if you don't ever want to read it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would avoid using `""`. How about simple `0` ?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set akey 0
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage akey
(integer) 48
127.0.0.1:6379> set akey ""
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage akey
(integer) 50
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: I think this is probably a better answer, in terms of real memory consumption.

Comment: A `0` has a greater likelihood of being a _useful_ value, whereas `""` already essentially means empty or nothing. `""` is better when dealing with integer values is a possibility (or becomes a possibility in the future).

Answer (score 63):

Who said that you should actually store anything in redis key?

Empty string `""` is a perfectly valid value for a redis key, and it's a shortest possible one:

```
> SET foo ""
OK
> GET foo
""
> BITCOUNT foo
(integer) 0
```

Comment: When using the StackExchange Redis client this can be detected by seeing that a RedisValue.IsNull is false but IsNullOrEmpty is true (what an api!).

Comment: this should be more clear that it is the value for a key 'foo' and not setting key to ""

Comment: When examined with `MEMORY USAGE [key]`, a value of `0` has a smaller footprint than an empty string. [See the answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292672)

Answer (score 9):

I would store one byte of data that could also be broadly interpreted as "truthy", such as the ASCII character `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you serialize everything coming to and from redis, yourself? If so, you may consider using a sentinel value (like a NONE constant, etc.) which is set to something like 'None'.