# Is it possible to get a Redis key even if it's expired(but still exists in Redis)?

Tags: redis

Since the Redis expires keys in passive and active way,

Is there any way to get a key even if its **expire time has passed**(but **still exists** in Redis)?

Comment: Do you mean just the key? Or also the value? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328058/redis-2-8-notifications-get-value-instead-of-key-on-expire#

Comment: Key and value. I checked it, it's interesting but isn't what i meaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The key (and its value) will be expired automatically eventually, or upon trying to access it (i.e. passively or actively).

Answer (score 2):

[`DEBUG OBJECT myKey`](https://redis.io/commands/debug-object) will return info about the key **even when it is expired timewise** - if it has not been garbage-collected (actively-expired) or passively-expired (accessed) yet.

To test this, you can disable the background (active) expiring with `DEBUG SET-ACTIVE-EXPIRE 0`. Use carefully. Restore with `DEBUG SET-ACTIVE-EXPIRE 1`

Note the `DEBUG OBJECT myKey` returns the memory address, so if you really need to see the value, you'll have to [explore the RAM contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/exploring-ram-contents).

```
> DEBUG OBJECT myKey
Value at:0x7fff70629920 refcount:1 encoding:embstr serializedlength:4 ...
```

`DEBUG OBJECT myKey` returns `(error) ERR no such key` if it has been expired already, actively or passively, or if it doesn't exist of course.

Comment: Thanks. Seems the best normal way is "shadow expiration key" https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647773/8712494